# Convert a non-isolated converter to an isolated converter

Tags: dc, ac, converter

Is there a way to convert a non-isolated converter(such as R-78C5.0-1.0) to an isolated converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no practical way. If you can use a transformer isolated supply on the input it will be isolated (by the transformer).

Comment: Thanks Spehro. You are ubiquitous. I figured I will start another thread which is more relevant to my issue with isolated converters. I will continue posting on the other thread. Would really appreciate it if you could give your input there.